# Crear nuevo nodo firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

Hola Buenas Tardes me pueden ayudar con la siguiente duda:

Creo un nodo nuevo,pero el nodo padre me lo crea aleatoriamente y no quiero que sea asi,deseo yo ponerle el nombre de el nodo padre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese nombre se pone solo,yo quiero definir el nombre de ese nodo.

Comment: puedes poner el codigo que usas para cargarlo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esos nodos con llaves al azar se generan cuando utilizas la operación `push()`, esta genera un ID único dentro del nodo para que puedas usar como identificador.

Si lo que quieres es es crear nodos con id propios todo lo que tienes que hacer es llamar set() a la direccion que incluya el **nodo padre  /  el id** que deseas utilizar.

Ej:

```
 firebase.database().ref('clientes/' + 1234).set({
    nombre: nameInput,
    email: emailInput,
    telefono : phoneInput
  });
```